# ::before pseudo element doesn't become first child of originating list element

Tags: css, pseudo-element

I tried making an inline list of links separated by `|` marks. It might be hacky, but I though it should work with using `::before` pseudo elements:

```css
li {
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
}
li:not(:first-child) ::before {
  content: "|";
  margin: 0 1em;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="..">Example 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="..">Example 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="..">Example 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

It looks about fine, but for some reason the `|` became part of the link element. It's clickable and highlighted in the same standard blue.

I expected the pseudo element to become the first child of the `li` element, *before* the content that consists of the link. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: typo: remove *space* before `::before` see https://jsfiddle.net/jucxwbrs/

Comment: OMG, such a noob mistake :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You literally have an extra space before `::before`, if you remove that it looks fine.

```css
li {
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
}
li:not(:first-child)::before {
  content: "|";
  margin: 0 1em;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="..">Example 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="..">Example 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="..">Example 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you made a syntax error. This should be:

```
li:not(:first-child)::before
```

Comment: it's not an *error* but simply a different selector

Comment: It becomes a syntax error if it's not working as expected x)